# Performance difference between linq to xml and xml serialization

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, linq-to-xml

I would like to create an xml file (100 lines, 5 namespaces and 30 different tags, 20 attributes total). I already have a hardcoded xml example but i need to write some c# code to generate a dynamic xml and to fill the values, which of course can change. Performance is a concern.

1. Should I use **linq to xml** and create all the tags with **XDocument and XElement** and provide variables that contain the dynamic values
2. Since i have already an xml example, create a schema.xsd and provide the values to the object

The xml (the object stream) will be sent via HTTP POST every second to a web service.

I am going to timetest both versions but i was just curious if someone already did that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The LINQ to XML version should have better performance.**

If you want to optimize it even more you probably should consider direct string concatenation (but that's not a best practice and the performance gain won't be significant).

The next performance option will be XmlTextWriter. Probably the fastest way to write XML "correctly" - it don't need to create XML object model like LINQ to XML, so should be significantly faster.

You can optimize serialization a bit if you cache the XmlSerializer instance and won't create it every time. Then it will also be relatively fast, though definitely slower than direct XML writes.

Comment: ok thx. For small "static" xml i always used string concatenation, but this is getting bigger and schould be maintainable. Are we talking here about 10ms or maybe 200ms? from your experience

Comment: depends on the size of course (how many attributes, total number of symbols in result XML would be more useful than number of lines). But I suppose it will be more close to 10ms that to 200ms if all operations are in-mrmory

Comment: I added one more option to answer: XmlTextWriter. It's not often used nowadays, but it's definitely faster than LINQ and probably will give time under 10ms.

Comment: I just reminded the case when we needed to optimize XML serialization in probably similar situation in web-application. There were plenty of caches including binary stream caching with reused parts of XML. The result performance allowed to handle 400-600 requests per second. And our XML had the size about 30-40KB. So I think 10 ms in your case is really not the best possible option - you can simply get 1 ms.

Comment: Don't use XmlTextWriter. Use XmlWriter.Create.

Comment: I suppose John meant not to create XmlTextWriter directly using constructor. Because XmlWriter.Create will anyway create XmlTextWriter in your case... But that's anyway important comment. Thanks, John